# What is the naming convention for assembles template plugins?

Tags: naming-conventions, assemble, nunjucks

I'm creating a nunjucks plug-in for [Assemble v0.6.0](https://github.com/assemble/assemble/tree/v0.6.0). It seems it's using [Template](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/template)(I think it was previously called [Engine](https://www.npmjs.com/package/engine)), which also powers [Verb](https://github.com/assemble/verb).

should I be calling the plugin "engine-nunjucks", "template-nunjucks", "assemble-plugin-nunjucks", "assemble-nunjucks"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Verb, Assemble, Template can weigh in here

Not sure if you noticed, but @doowb is co-creator of all of those projects ;)

It's a good question and one we have started to document with the pending v0.6.0 release coming, but we should probably step on the gas and get these things published.

**Short answer**

- if it's a plugin (like gulp plugins) then `assemble-*` is a good way to go. Plugins follow gulp convention and style guidelines. Don't go by naming conventions of old pre-v0.6.0 assemble plugins/middleware. We're asking the gods of poor-naming-decisisions to absolve us of those sins so we can move on (and deprecate them). Hopefully we'll get past that
- if it's an engine, then use `engine-*` for naming. Code-wise, engines follow consolidate convention when async, and [engines][1] convention when sync (which is just basically consolidate without the callbacks). Since engines can be published with both sync and async methods, `engine-foo` is probably always a good bet.
- If it's a helper and it's generic, use `helper-*`. if it requires a specific engine, use the engine in the name: `handlebars-helper-*`. If it requires assemble, name it `assemble-helper-*`
- If it's a loader, use `loader-*`. If it's a loader that is specific to assemble, then use `assemble-loader-*`, or if it can be used by any library that implements Template, then use `template-loader-*`.

I think the overriding convention is to just err on the side of explicitly naming what the module is associated with, so it's easier to find by other devs in the community. The only exception being actual plugins, since we're trying to stick to gulp convention (instead of doing `assemble-plugin-*`)

Comment: that's a good enough starting point to dump straight into documentation regarding this topic.

Comment: I was hoping to at least get a start on it. this helped me crystallize some thoughts, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From looking at your repository, I think `engine-nunjucks` fits best since you're creating a rendering engine for `template`. This is similar to `engine-handlebars`, `engine-lodash`, `engine-less`, and `engine-assemble` that we have already.

Comment: That was my first guess, but `Engine` doesn't exist any more. I'm hoping the creator of Verb, Assemble, Template can weigh in here to start an official guideline on naming conventions for Assemble, Template and Verb.

Comment: oops, apologies @dwoob.